# Jenkins Deploy to container glassfish4

Tags: docker, glassfish, jenkins

Olá,
  Basicamente eu construo meu war usando o maven e chamo o app deploy to container pra rodar uma instância do glassfish que está em outro container, aponto os caminhos mas me é retornada uma exception
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e essa é a configuração :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguem ja passou por isso e conseguiu contornar ?

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem ? 
Por um acaso, você tentou usar o [Deploy to Container Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/deploy) ? Ele faz o deployment remoto do Glassfish 2.x/3.x/4.x .